# How to correctly map the express keys on my Huion H950P drawing tablet?

Tags: drivers, manjaro, tablet

I am using a Huion H950P USB drawing tablet on Manjaro Linux (KDE, Kernel 6.1.31).

As a driver I installed the `digimend-kernel-drivers-dkms` from the AUR I also use the official `kcm-wacomtablet` package to get the appropriate entry within my systems settings.

Most things (i.e. mapping the graphics tablet to my main screen and rotating it by 180° since I'm left-handed) work fine however setting up the express keys does not.

The set keys have seemingly no effect on the inputs generated from the tablet and reset to default (empty) on every system reboot.

The weirdest thing is that I was working successfully with said tablet about half a year ago, but right now nothing seems to function as it should.

Does anyone know how to diagnostic and/or fix the issue?